# Which of the following relations is/are true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Which of the following is true?

1. $n^6\equiv n(\mod 42)$
2. $n^7\equiv n(\mod 42)$
3. $n^6\equiv 1(\mod 42)$
4. $n^8\equiv n(\mod 42)$

I don't know why it is not obvious to me, but I know that $3$ is not true. What is the general theorem working here? I know that $n^p\equiv n(\mod p)$ where $p$ is a prime, but I don't see it is working here.

Help me out.

Comment: Hint: do you know any way to reduce to the case of a prime number?

Comment: Do I have to divide by the gcd$(7,42)$?

Comment: I was going to suggest using the Chinese remainder theorem and solving the problem for each prime separately.

Comment: Oh ok I am thinking about that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2)$ is true, $1),3),4)$ are wrong. Note $42=2\cdot 3\cdot 7$.

$n^7-n=n\left(n^6-1\right)=n(n-1)(n+1)\left(n^4+n^2+1\right)$ contains a product of three consecutive integers, so it's divisible by $2$ and $3$. By Fermat's Little theorem $7\mid n^7-n$.

$n=2$ is a counterexample for $1),3),4)$.